# MySQL single query with parent child relation stored across tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as

table1

```
| ID | Description  | Type   |
| 1  | Desc 1       | type1  |
| 2  | Desc 2       | type1  |
| 3  | Desc 11      | type1  |
| 4  | Desc 21      | type1  |
| 5  | Desc 12      | type1  |
| 6  | Desc 31      | type1  |
| 7  | Desc 3       | type1  |
| 8  | Desc 111     | type1  |
| 9  | Desc 112     | type1  |
```

relationtable1
table1.id <-> relationtable1.rel_to_id and table1.id <-> relationtable1.rel_from_id

```
| ID | rel_to_id | rel_from_id  | relation   |
| 1  |    3      | 1            | parent     |
| 2  |    4      | 2            | parent     |
| 3  |    5      | 1            | parent     |
| 4  |    6      | 7            | parent     |
| 5  |    8      | 3            | parent     |
| 6  |    9      | 3            | parent     |
```

Please help me with a mysql query which will yield me the 
Expected Result :

```
| ID | Description  | Type   |
| 1  | Desc 1       | type1  |
| 3  | Desc 11      | type1  |
| 8  | Desc 111     | type1  |
| 9  | Desc 112     | type1  |
| 5  | Desc 12      | type1  |
| 2  | Desc 2       | type1  |
| 4  | Desc 21      | type1  |
| 7  | Desc 3       | type1  |
| 6  | Desc 31      | type1  |
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/793f3/2)

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)? It helps to have something to play about with when answering these type of questions.

Comment: Isn't the expected results the same as `table1` ORDERED BY Description? What is the `relationtable1` for?

Comment: ok, I will create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @JayKazama the Type is different, In my case its either development, bug, Requirement, etc.

Comment: sql fiddle here --> [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/793f3/2)

Comment: If you are having "rel_to_id" and "rel_from_id", what exactly is the point of having "relation" column? Any chance you meant to call it level/depth? Because a depth column is required to map layered data (i.e: 3,8,9 in output) in order.

Comment: The relation column has many type of relations, My query is specific to get only "parent"s. @JA

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the relation table you provided (issuerelationtable) is not a valid Clousure table for generating adjacent list. Here's how it should be storing references..

```
CREATE TABLE `issuerelationtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rel_to_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rel_from_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;



INSERT INTO `issuerelationtable` (`id`, `rel_to_id`, `rel_from_id`, `relation`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, NULL),
(2, 3, 1, NULL),
(3, 5, 1, NULL),
(4, 8, 1, NULL),
(5, 9, 1, NULL),
(6, 2, 2, NULL),
(7, 4, 2, NULL),
(8, 4, 4, NULL),
(9, 3, 3, NULL),
(10, 8, 3, NULL),
(11, 9, 3, NULL),
(12, 5, 5, NULL),
(13, 6, 6, NULL),
(14, 7, 7, NULL),
(15, 6, 7, NULL),
(16, 8, 8, NULL),
(17, 9, 9, NULL);
```

To achieve the desired output, query should be..

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(it.id),
  it.description,
  it.type
FROM
  issuetable it
  INNER JOIN issuerelationtable irt ON it.id=irt.rel_from_id
WHERE
  irt.rel_to_id IN (SELECT id FROM issuetable)
ORDER BY
  it.description
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did not work for me, 
the sometimes there are no children in the issue relation table, they are not shown in your query..
Couple of reasons -> Order by description..

Comment: The query outputs exactly how you wanted, considering the relation table is updated.

Comment: Sorry. The relation table has some string value relation name, It cannot be set to NULL.

Comment: Regarding to my comment on the relation column: I didn't need the column, so left it as NULL. Also, in order to populate the records as you desired (ORDER BY), there HAS to be a column for level/depth.

Comment: Additional link, if you wish to try please use this one [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2648/3)

Comment: As I mentioned, the way you are storing relation data is not Valid for the purpose (Check Adjacency/Closure definition). Either use a valid data structure or implement much-complex stored procedure/recurrent SELECT statement.